# Predicting using Keras Timedistributed layer

Tags: time-series, keras, panel-data, regularized

I am trying to model two time series at once using Keras with LSTM and a Timedistributed layer. The data I'm considering is a regression setup, with two cosine waves with some added gaussian noise. However the model has a lot of trouble predicting out of sample. Is this to be expected, or have I just got too few layers?

In the output below the blue circles are the training data, the green squares are the predicted values for the training data, the red squares are the test data, and the blue triangles are the predicted values for the test data. It is clear that the model overfits on the training data, and doesn't find the underlying structure in data. I have tried using regularization as well, without any succes.

```
# Import models
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier as KC
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.regularizers import l1
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data
t = 100
n = 2
xtrain = np.zeros((n,t,1))
xtest = np.zeros((n,t,1))
ytrain = np.zeros((n,t,1))
ytest = np.zeros((n,t,1))+np.random.normal(0,1,(n,t,1))

change_point = 3.14*2

for i in range(xtrain.shape[0]):
    xtrain[i,:,0] = np.random.uniform(0,change_point,t)
    xtest[i,:,0] = np.random.uniform(change_point,2*change_point,t)

ytrain[0,:,0] = np.cos(xtrain[0,:,0])+np.random.normal(0,0.2,t)
ytrain[1,:,0] = np.cos(xtrain[1,:,0])+np.random.normal(0,0.2,t)
ytest[0,:,0] = np.cos(xtest[0,:,0])+np.random.normal(0,0.2,t)
ytest[1,:,0] = np.cos(xtest[1,:,0])+np.random.normal(0,0.2,t)

m = Sequential()
m.add(LSTM(90,input_shape=(t,1), return_sequences = True))
m.add(LSTM(90, return_sequences = True))
m.add(LSTM(90, return_sequences = True))
#m.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences = True))
m.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))


m.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')

m.fit(xtrain,ytrain,nb_epoch=400, batch_size=2)
ypred = m.predict(xtest)
ytrain_pred = m.predict(xtrain)

ps = 0
plt.scatter(xtrain[ps,:,0],ytrain[ps,:,0])
plt.scatter(xtest[ps,:,0],ytest[ps,:,0], marker='s', c='r')
plt.scatter(xtrain[ps,:,0],ytrain_pred[ps,:,0],marker = 's',c='g')
plt.scatter(xtest[ps,:,0],ypred[ps,:,0], marker='^', c='b')
```

[image: First plot]
[image: Second plot]